# Push up view problem when focus textField in SwfitUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
struct TextFieldTest: View {
    
    @State var textfieldText: String = ""
    @FocusState var isTextFieldFocus: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0 ..< 5) { num in
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                            .frame(height: 100)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    }
                    TextField("something here ...", text: $textfieldText, axis: .vertical)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(minHeight: 120, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
                        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.3).cornerRadius(10))
                        .padding(.bottom)
                        .focused($isTextFieldFocus)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            isTextFieldFocus = true
                        }
                        .id("textField")
                }
                .padding()
                .onChange(of: textfieldText) { newValue in
                    proxy.scrollTo("textField", anchor: .bottom)
                }
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification)) { notification in
                        withAnimation() {
                            proxy.scrollTo("textField", anchor: .bottom)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I touch the text field and the keyboard appears, it scrolls to the bottom anchor of the text field, but when the text changes and the frame of the text field goes below the keyboard, it does not scroll to the bottom anchor of the text field. However, if I do not specify a minimum height for the background of the text field, it scrolls to the bottom anchor of the text field whenever the content of the text field changes.

Also, if you specify a minimum height and it automatically scrolls to the bottom of the TextField when the keyboard is raised, and then the text in the TextField gets longer and goes over the minimum height, it should scroll to the bottom because of the .onChange, but it doesn't work. However, if you scroll to the bottom by hand after it goes over the frame, you can see that it moves to the bottom whenever the text changes.

Do you know why this is happening and how to specify a minimum height and have the TextField automatically scroll when the frame goes over the keyboard?

I wanted the textField to continue scrolling to the bottom as the keyboard rises and the textField adds text, but no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From trial and error, I found that scrolling the scroll view for a little bit before inserting a new line produces the correct behaviour.

So I tried doing that programmatically, and it does work.

First, make a view for the scroll view to temporarily scroll to. You can do this by simply surrounding the `TextField` with a `VStack` or similar.

```
VStack {
    TextField("something here ...", text: $textfieldText, axis: .vertical)
        .padding()
        .frame(minHeight: 120, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.3).cornerRadius(10))
        .padding(.bottom)
        .focused($isTextFieldFocus)
        .onTapGesture {
            isTextFieldFocus = true
        }
        .id("textField")
}.id("placeholder")
```

In `onChange`, scroll to `placeholder` first, then to `textField`. You need to put either or both of these `scrollTo`s in a `DispatchQueue.main.async` block (found by trial and error) for this to work. I assume this is to allow the text field to re-layout, and only start scrolling after that is done.

```
.onChange(of: textfieldText) { _ in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        proxy.scrollTo("placeholder", anchor: .bottom)
        proxy.scrollTo("textField", anchor: .bottom)
    }
}
```

I doubt this is the best solution for this though, unless the weird scrolling behaviour is a bug.

Comment: Thanks! it's working the way I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can have another element at the bottom of the page which you use as the target for scrolling. The id of this element needs to change for scrolling to work, so this can be done in your `.onChange` callback. The element itself can be in the background and have such low opacity that it is effectively invisible - a `Divider` works nicely. In fact, applying `.hidden()` also worked sometimes, but I think it works more reliably using low opacity. See also the note about reliability that follows the code.

```swift
struct TextFieldTest: View {

    @State var textfieldText: String = ""
    @FocusState var isTextFieldFocus: Bool
    @State private var dividerId = UUID()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    // contents as before
                }
                .background(alignment: .bottom) {
                    Divider()
                        .opacity(0.001)
                        .id(dividerId)
                }
                .padding()
                .onChange(of: textfieldText) { newValue in
                    dividerId = UUID()
                    proxy.scrollTo(dividerId, anchor: .bottom)
                }
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification)) { notification in
                    withAnimation() {
                        proxy.scrollTo(dividerId, anchor: .bottom)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my tests on a real iPhone 8 running iOS 16.6, this worked sometimes, but not always. I tried a few different ideas (such as, scrolling asynchronously), but wasn't able to find a way to get it working reliably every time. I don't know if the issue is related to spelling suggestions - I was just entering junk into the text field for the purpose of a quick test.